# How to check is the last condition true?

Tags: pine-script

I have 2 conditions:
`cond_1 = rsi > 70`
`cond_2 = rsi < 30`
Let say cond_2 **has to be the last condition** before:

`cond_3 = close > base`
 How to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a `var bool` that retains it's value and can be flipped when 1 & 2 occur. Once `cond_2` has occurred, `last_was_cond_2` will remain true until `cond_1` happens.

```
cond_1 = rsi > 70
cond_2 = rsi < 30

var bool last_was_cond_2 = false

if cond_1
    last_was_cond_2 := false
else if cond_2
    last_was_cond_2 := true
    
cond_3 = last_was_cond_2 and close > base
```